# a0poster pdf size problem

Tags: paper-size, posters

I am trying to write a poster using the `a0poster` class. I have encountered a problem that drives me crazy. It seems that the class creates the correct size of text and spacing but outputs everything on a A4 paper size. So my `.tex` file is the following.

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0]{a0poster}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse dolor sem, vulputate nec interdum sit amet, convallis sollicitudin ex. Cras hendrerit, augue at scelerisque hendrerit, dui urna aliquet orci, in maximus urna leo vitae nibh.
\vspace{1em}
\hrule
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse dolor sem, vulputate nec interdum sit amet, convallis sollicitudin ex. Cras hendrerit, augue at scelerisque hendrerit, dui urna aliquet orci, in maximus urna leo vitae nibh.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse dolor sem, vulputate nec interdum sit amet, convallis sollicitudin ex. Cras hendrerit, augue at scelerisque hendrerit, dui urna aliquet orci, in maximus urna leo vitae nibh.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This `.tex` file produces the following `.pdf`

[image]

Any thoughts on that? Does it create the same `.pdf` on your systems? So far I have tried on 2 different computers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The default paper size is `a4` or `letter`.

Comment: Checking with package `printlen`, the paperwidth is 839.6 mm, DIN A0 would be 841 mm, so it is definitely not A4. The pointsize of the current font is 24.88 pt.

Comment: At no point in the minimal example, file `pdftex.def` is loaded. Please load package `geometry`as well. :-)

Comment: `\usepackage[a0paper]{geometry}` should help

Comment: Wait, the a0poster package doesn't change the paper size? Is this on purpose?

Comment: as mentioned below, `a0poster` comes with a driver for `dvips` to set the correct page size, but not for direct pdf output. This is where file `pdftex.def` drops in.

Answer (score 1):

You can load package `geometry` to get the right page size, it will change your margins though. Giving the package  option `pass` will prevent that.

On the other hand, you can as well load package `graphicx`  or load file `pdftex.def` in your preamble.

Comment: I thought that the a0 option takes care of this. Isn't this the case?

Comment: @tst No, apperently not ;-) The correct pagesize is set when `pdftex.def` is read, which is loaded by multiple packages, but unfortunately not by `a0pster` by default (as there is also XeLaTeX and others). `a0poster` isn't exactely the newest in the bunch of poster classes and, as you mentioned, it works with `dvips` very fine. The class takes care, but back then, pdflatex wasn't as widespread as it is today.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a problem with PDFlatex. Compiling with latex creates a correct size '.dvi' file and the the conversion to '.pdf' creates the expected result.

Edit: Well, *correct size .dvi* is not a precise statement, but I guess you know what I mean.